# Can someone please explain to me the quickest and easiest way to share one link on facebook from an Android activity?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Long story short: I have an android app, from which I want users to be able to share the play store link of my app on their facebook walls.

I don't care about fancy logins with custom user pictures, or taking over the user's news feed, or having facebook take over my app...

I don't need this to happen automatically; a simple redirect to facebook.com or the facebook app with the link already typed in the field the user can submit is all I require.

Is there any way to accomplish this without implementing facebook login or open graph?

If so... HOW?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Android share intent like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

More info can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: YOUR RESPONSE WAS... SO FAST :) trying this now, accepting soon after :)

Comment: Added some clarification but I think the android developer site is everything you need for this kind of thing, this is exactly what you need.